# Notification: different large icon for normal and expanded state

Tags: android, android-notifications

I saw the following on the notifications of the [NTV app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lineas.lit.ntv.android):

The notification has a picture as the large icon (photo), but when the notification is expanded, the icon changes to their app logo.

The image changes between the two as the notification is expanded and retracted.

I am talking about the notification with the text 'Innenminister: ...' seen in the two pictures.

I'm pretty sure they use the standard [Notification.BigPictureStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html)

Any ideas on how that can be achieved?

[image: Non-expanded notification showing photo of bus as large icon]

[image: Expanded notification showing the NTV icon as large icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Notification.BigPictureStyle` [has `bigLargeIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html#bigLargeIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon)), described as: "Override the large icon when the big notification is shown." I would assume that they are using this, given your description.

Comment: Thanks. My fault for exploring APIs by typing 'xy.set', then looking at the autocomplete suggestions ... I miss out on stuff ;)